# writing more than one Mat variable to an XML file using filestorage in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a problem writing more than one Mat variable to  an XML file  using  filestorage  in opencv. I'm using VC++ 2012 and I can write each Mat in a separate xml file without any problem. but when I try to write a second  Mat object it throws an exception as:
Unhandled exception at at 0x000007FEFD06B3DD in test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00000000002ABE70.

I found this topic once here but the answers did not help me. the part of code that trows the exception is as:

```
FileStorage fs("c:\\test.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);
Mat cameraMatrix = (Mat_<double>(3,3) << 1000, 0, 320, 0, 1000, 240, 0, 0, 1);
Mat distCoeffs = (Mat_<double>(5,1) << 0.1, 0.01, -0.001, 0, 0); 
fs<<"cameraMatrix" << cameraMatrix ;
fs<< "distCoeffs" << distCoeffs;
fs.release();
```

The exception is thrown on the second  fs << :

```
fs<< "distCoeffs" << distCoeffs;
```

would you please help me with this . I have take this code from a sample in opencv document.

Comment: Run in debug and get the error message. Are you sure you are linking OpenCV built with vc11 compiler?

Comment: I'm already running it in debug mode and I'm using many other opencv functions without any problem so I'm sure that built is correct. Also I have mentioned the error message in my main post.

Comment: The code is working ok. Though, you probably want to change destination folder since you probably don't have write access to "C:".  Try simply with `FileStorage fs("test.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);`, the file will be in the project directory. The fact that some functions already work is not a guarantee that you linked properly. Just to be sure, can you show your "Library Directories"?

Comment: I have write access to c: because when I write only one Mat it works. Also my library directory is "C:\OpenCV3.0\build\x64\vc11\lib"

Comment: Problem is solved finally, In the project configuration properties> Linker > input > additional dependencies  I had set opencv_world300.lib while it should have been opencv_world300d.lib. Changing that the problem is solved now

Comment: Ok, glad you make it work ;D

Comment: Please either post an answer and accept it, or delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved finally, In the project configuration properties> Linker > input > additional dependencies I had set opencv_world300.lib while it should have been opencv_world300d.lib. Changing that the problem is solved now